# Is milk coffee good or bad?

Tags: health, milk, steamed-milk

I always had loved drinking coffee like this: a full hot cup of milk and a teaspoon of coffee (instant coffee) and teaspoon of brown sugar. Some one told me it’s not healthy.

I love latte but not without sugar free synfuel and that too is bad.

Is it true that the way I have coffee is bad? I have like 2 or sometimes 3 cups a day.

Answer (score -1):

I'm no nutritionist, biologist, biochemist, or doctor. But I can tell you what Ive heard and learned over the years.

Coffee itself isn't inherently bad for you. Some science suggests its good for you in fact.  The problem is in how we choose to prepare it for drinking.

Sugar and cream... both up for debate I think. Sugar is an essential component to life. Milk isn't bad for you either, necessarily.  Like anything else though, moderation is key.  Milk does contain fats and sugars.  So if you're watching your intake of these things for health sake, then milk contributes its own parts.  Aside from that, unless you're lactose intolerant, milk is a-okay to consume.

I like lattes too but you need to use espresso for that.  Your instant coffee version doesn't sound particularly appetizing to me.

I find that whenever I use straight milk in regular coffee, I don't know if its the heat or the acids of the coffee working on the milk, but I get this sour taste after twenty minutes or so. I don't get that flavor with other creamers, even dairy-based creamers. I've started using those flavored Carnation-brand creamers because of it. Oddly, I also don't get that sour flavor when I use straight milk and espresso.

Comment: "Sugar is an essential component to life". This is not true. Sugar is not _essential_. There are essential amino acid. If you don't get them, you'll die. If you don't get vitamins, you'll die. If you don't get fat, you'll die. If you don't get sugar, you'll live. It is however quite important with enough reserves for hard physical work for longer duration,  otherwise your body will start break down muscle mass to provide enough energy (as it assumes that you are trying to flee from mortal danger, so 'eating' the body is better than being eaten).

Comment: @Pete I think maybe you should post in the nutrition stackexchange, not the coffee stackexchange. Just a thought.

Comment: Instant coffee will cause a strange taste in milk that has been heated too much. A near-boiling milk drink made with instant coffee will cause that strange aftertaste you mention. Milk should be kept under 170° F to preserve taste.